# Format numerous floats in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I need help, I am unable to display the seaborn plot well.

[image: figure image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

dataset = pd.read_csv('sales.csv', header=0,sep =',',
                  usecols = [1,2,3,4])
#remove NaN
dataset.dropna(inplace = True)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
sns.regplot(data=df, x='TV', y='sales')
plt.show()
```

As example for sales_csv :

```
id,TV,radio,newspaper,sales
1,230.10000000,37.8,69.2,22.1
2,1e12,39.3,45.1,10.4
3,17.2,45.9,69.3,9.3
4,151.5,41.3,58.5,18.5
5,180.8,10.8,58.4,12.9
5,180.8,10.8,58.4,12.9
6,8.7,48.9,75,7.2
7,57.5,32.8,23.5,11.8
8,120.2,19.6,11.6,13.2
9,8.6,2.1,1,4.8
10,199.8,2.6,21.2,10.6
11,66.1,5.8,24.2,8.6
12,214.7,24,4,17.4
13,23.8,35.1,65.9,9.2
14,97.5,7.6,7.2,9.7
15,1,32.9,46,19
16,195.4,47.7,52.9,22.4
17,67.8,36.6,114,12.5
18,281.4,39.6,55.8,24.4
19,69.2,20.5,18.3,11.3
20,147.3,23.9,19.1,14.6
21,218.4,27.7,53.4,18
22,237.4,5.1,23.5,12.5
23,13.2,15.9,49.6,5.6
24,228.3,16.9,26.2,15.5
25,62.3,12.6,18.3,9.7
26,262.9,3.5,19.5,12
27,142.9,29.3,12.6,15
28,240.1,16.7,22.9,15.9
29,248.8,27.1,22.9,18.9
30,70.6,16,40.8,10.5
31,292.9,28.3,43.2,21.4
32,112.9,17.4,38.6,11.9
33,97.2,1.5,30,9.6
34,1e12,20,0.3,17.4
```

Comment: Without some samples from `sales.csv` this is hard to answer to.

Comment: Sorry it is my first post and I am getting the web.  https://pastebin.com/QiffD8JG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the dataset contains values of `1e12` used to represent NA. These values should be replaced or dropped. The easiest way to convert `'1e12'` to `NA` is via the `na_values='1e12'` parameter to `pd.read_csv()`.

Alternatively, `dataset.replace(1e12, pd.NA, inplace=True)` can be used to convert them later.

Note that `dataset` already is a dataframe, so the call `df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)` is unnecessary.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('sales.csv', header=0, sep=',', na_values='1e12',
                      usecols=[1, 2, 3, 4])
# remove NaN
dataset.dropna(inplace=True)
sns.regplot(data=dataset, x='TV', y='sales')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you very much friend, several days stagnant, and with such a simple solution. Really thank you very much!